# Background image height 100% or 100vh problem

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

How to solve the problem that the URL field affects the overall height? Please help thank you

```
body,html {
 height:100%
}
```

When there is a display address bar

```
.bg {
 min-height:100%
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url(xxx.png);
}
```

[image]

When you scroll down, the background will be blank when the address bar is hidden

```
.bg {
 min-height:100%
background-size: cover;
 background-image: url(xxx.png);
}
```

[image]

My solution is to change it to min-height:100vh, but a piece of material will appear when sliding up, and the whole thing is not

```
smooth.
.bg {
 min-height:100vh
background-size: cover;
 background-image: url(xxx.png);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note "hieght" is not how you spell "height"

Comment: The problem is that you have misspelled height as hieght.

Comment: already edited .thanks for reminding.But not that problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-attachment` property,
It will attach the background to your position.

Try like this:

```
.bg {
   min-height:100%
   background-size: cover;
   background-image: url(xxx.png);
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

Let me know your result.

Comment: When the URL bar is hidden, it is still blank.